# How to check if a web browser has a page loaded?

Tags: vb.net, web, visual-studio-2013

Im making a bookmark system for a web browser and
i need help with checking if a web browser has a page loaded

The code:

```
    If (The web browser has anything loaded) Then
        System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Users\02bore23\AppData\Roaming\SimpleWeb\Bookmarks\bookMark1.swph")
        System.IO.File.Create("C:\Users\02bore23\AppData\Roaming\SimpleWeb\Bookmarks\bookMark1.swph")
        Dim File1 As System.IO.StreamWriter
        File1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\02bore23\AppData\Roaming\SimpleWeb\Bookmarks\bookMark1.swph", True)
        File1.WriteLine(New Uri(WebBrowser1.Url.ToString))
        File1.Close()
    End If
```

Where it says "The Web browser has anything loaded" is where i need help

Comment: How about handling the [LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event? or `WebBrowser1.ReadyState =WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WebBrowser.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
If this property equals `""` nothing is loaded, else you can save the bookmark.

```
If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString <> "" Then
```